# How do I perform multiple operations in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, operation

```
L = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(5) random.randint(0,12) for i in range(2)]
```

How do I get it to pick 5 random numbers between (0,50), then 2 random numbers between(0,12)?

Comment: whats your desired output? and don't name your list `list`

Comment: List comprehensions are just for loops that build a list. If you can express your needs in a regular `for` loop with a `list.append(...)` part, then you can probably make it a list comprehension too.

Comment: It's only named list on here, Not in my actual code. My desired outcome is a list of 7 random numbers, 5 that have been picked from a range of (0,50) and 2 that have been picked from a range of (0,12)

Comment: You may be interested in the `timeit` results I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can vary the second argument to `randint()` based on the value of `i`:

```
[randint(0, 50 if i < 5 else 12) for i in range(7)]
```

The `50 if i < 5 else 12` expression will change what is passed to `random.randint()` for the last two iterations.

There are many more variations you can spell this in. List comprehensions are a bunch of loops and `if` filters that repeatedly execute the expression at the front. There are lots of ways to spell *vary the arguments to a function call based on the iteration values* in expressions.

For example, you could record those arguments in [`functools.partial()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
from random import randint

rint50 = partial(randint, 0, 50)
rint12 = partial(randint, 0, 12)
[rint() for rint in [rint50] * 5 + [rint12] * 2]
```

The possibilities are endless. Lambdas, `randint(0, upperbound)`, `randint(*args)`, a function that'll vary its results depending on how often it has been called, etc. But I wouldn't argue that any of these are actually more readable or understandable.

For this case, with just 7 values, I'd just concatenate the two lists:

```
[randint(0, 50) for _ in range(5)] + [randint(0, 12) for _ in range(2)]
```

as it's just cleaner and more readable. The small performance cost of creating a 3rd list that contains the results of the two list comprehensions is negligible here.

Comment: Nice! I think the only thing I don't like about list comprehension is readability.

Comment: @artomason: that depends on how you are are using them. Here, the expression is easily too ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this maybe, concatenating 2 lists:

```
from random import randint
my_list = [randint(0,50) for i in range(5)] + [randint(0,12) for i in range(2)]
```

Comment: Perfect man, Thank you! I must have missed it in my frustration!

Answer (score 3):

Don't reuse the name `list`.  One way would be to loop through an iterable of the bounds, and send those to `randint`

```
from random import randint

lst = [randint(*bounds) for bounds in [(0, 50)]*5 + [(0, 12)]*2]
```

You could also use `itertools.chain` and `itertools.repeat` to avoid building that list of bounds

```
lst = [randint(*bounds) for bounds in chain(repeat((0, 50), 5), repeat((0, 12), 2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
l = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(5)]
l.extend([random.randint(0,12) for i in range(2)])

print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation that avoids doing an `if` test on every iteration. It also uses `randrange`, which is slightly more efficient than `randint`.

```
from random import randrange
lst = [randrange(hi) for num, hi in ((5, 51), (2, 13)) for _ in range(num)]
print(lst)
```

**typical output**

```
[10, 31, 46, 25, 23, 6, 5]
```

This is equivalent to

```
lst = []
for num, hi in ((5, 51), (2, 13)):
    for _ in range(num):
        lst.append(randrange(hi))
```

The outer loop selects `num`, the number of items in the sublist, and `hi` the size of the random range for that sublist; the inner loop generates the required amount of random numbers in the desired range.

---

FWIW, here's some [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat) code comparing the various algorithms that have been submitted. It also verifies that they produce the same results when given the same random seed. My simple verification code uses `eval`, so it can only test expressions, not statements, so it can't test jpp's or Abhishek's code; besides, jpp's Numpy code gives different results anyway, since it uses a different seeding algorithm. Please see the `timeit` docs for info on what `timeit` does, and how to interpret the results.

```
from timeit import Timer
import random
from random import randint, randrange, seed
from itertools import chain, repeat, starmap
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

imports = 'random, randint, randrange, seed, chain, repeat, starmap, partial, np'

commands = (
    ('Martijn', '', '[randint(0, 50 if i < 5 else 12) for i in range(7)]'),
    ('Martijn_partial', 
        'rint50 = partial(randint, 0, 50); rint12 = partial(randint, 0, 12)', 
        '[rint() for rint in [rint50] * 5 + [rint12] * 2]'
    ),
    ('Patrick', '', '[randint(*bounds) for bounds in [(0, 50)]*5 + [(0, 12)]*2]'),
    ('Patrick_chain', '', 
        '[randint(*bounds) for bounds in chain(repeat((0, 50), 5), repeat((0, 12), 2))]'
    ),
    ('Ralf', '', '[randint(0,50) for i in range(5)] + [randint(0,12) for i in range(2)]'),
    ('Abhishek', '', 'l = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(5)];'
        'l.extend([random.randint(0,12) for i in range(2)])'
    ),
    ('PM 2Ring', '', '[randrange(hi) for num, hi in ((5, 51), (2, 13)) for _ in range(num)]'),
    ('jpp', '', 'A = np.zeros(7); ' 
        'A[:5] = np.random.randint(0, 20, 5); A[5:] = np.random.randint(0, 12, 2)'
    ),
    ('Tanmay jain', '', 
        '[random.randint(0,50) if i < 5 else random.randint(0,12) for i in range(7)]'
    ),
    ('juanpa', '', '[random.randint(a,b) for args in (((0,50) for _ in range(5)),' 
        '((0, 12) for _ in range(2))) for a, b in args]'
    ),
    ('juanpa_starmap', '', 'list(starmap(random.randint,'
        'chain(repeat((0,50),5), repeat((0,12),2))))'
    ),
)

def verify():
    for name, setup, cmd in commands:
        if name in ('jpp', 'Abhishek'):
            continue
        seed(17)
        if setup:
            exec(setup)
        print('{:16}: {}'.format(name, eval(cmd)))
    print()

def time_test(loops):
    timings = []
    print('loops =', loops)
    for name, setup, cmd in commands:
        setup = 'from __main__ import ' + imports + ';' + setup
        t = Timer(cmd, setup=setup)
        result = sorted(t.repeat(3, loops))
        timings.append((result, name))
    timings.sort()
    for result, name in timings:
        print('{:16} : {}'.format(name, result))

verify()
time_test(5000)
```

**typical output**

```
Martijn         : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]
Martijn_partial : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]
Patrick         : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]
Patrick_chain   : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]
Ralf            : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]
PM 2Ring        : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]
Tanmay jain     : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]
juanpa          : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]
juanpa_starmap  : [33, 26, 19, 23, 18, 2, 12]

loops = 5000
jpp              : [0.23938178099342622, 0.24184146700281417, 0.3152835669970955]
PM 2Ring         : [0.26918871099769603, 0.27244400099880295, 0.2916741489971173]
Patrick          : [0.34155847399961203, 0.34415175200410886, 0.3531294650019845]
juanpa_starmap   : [0.3417540490045212, 0.34329504700144753, 0.3438059809996048]
Martijn          : [0.3509639670010074, 0.362117896998825, 0.547288200003095]
Martijn_partial  : [0.3511254819968599, 0.35262946599686984, 0.39430355399963446]
Patrick_chain    : [0.3541102219969616, 0.3545923809942906, 0.3555165420038975]
Tanmay jain      : [0.3558294050017139, 0.5510739650053438, 0.7693202439986635]
Ralf             : [0.3678122450000956, 0.44522786799643654, 0.44827762299973983]
juanpa           : [0.4089203829935286, 0.41227930299646687, 0.42410747800022364]
Abhishek         : [0.4811078249986167, 0.4942625819967361, 0.6255962599971099]
```

As you can see, jpp's Numpy code is the fastest. I expect that the speed difference would be even more apparent if we were generating a longer list of numbers.

These timing were performed on an ancient 32 bit single core 2GHz machine, running Python 3.6.0 on a Debian derivative distro. YMMV.

---

Here are timings for the production of lists (or arrays) of 50 + 20 = 70 values in the same ranges.

```
loops = 500
jpp              : [0.025625186994147953, 0.025764200996491127, 0.03122780400008196]
PM 2Ring         : [0.21989007600495825, 0.2200367909972556, 0.22065802400175016]
juanpa_starmap   : [0.3094131350007956, 0.3110805670003174, 0.31563361900043674]
Patrick_chain    : [0.3122365829985938, 0.31262181099737063, 0.3137894630053779]
Patrick          : [0.3130071220002719, 0.31769691400404554, 0.3179219129960984]
Ralf             : [0.31566168300196296, 0.3157304769993061, 0.3234770689959987]
Martijn          : [0.3193310350034153, 0.3275600470005884, 0.35491854500287445]
Martijn_partial  : [0.321399387998099, 0.3226969290044508, 0.32442738999816356]
Abhishek         : [0.32655813400197076, 0.3363869300010265, 0.3657162370000151]
Tanmay jain      : [0.32833286200184375, 0.33107244400162017, 0.39565577400207985]
juanpa           : [0.35968791200139094, 0.3754627199959941, 0.3933205349967466]
```

Comment: For 7 values, comparing timings is next to meaningless. Looking at this from a perf perspective really is a premature optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, you can via NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0) # for consistency / testing

A = np.zeros(7)
A[:5] = np.random.randint(0, 20, 5)
A[5:] = np.random.randint(0, 12, 2)

array([ 12.,  15.,   0.,   3.,   3.,   7.,   9.])
```

The benefit of this method, memory pre-allocation, will be evident with larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
since you want to pick 5 random values from 0 - 50( exclusive)
i = 0...4
and then you want to pick 2 random values from 0 - 12( exclusive)
i = 5 6
```

```
lst = [random.randint(0,50) if i < 5 else random.randint(0,12) for i in range(7)]

print(lst) # [7, 10, 40, 4, 38, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this using list-comprehensions and only built-ins, some monstrosity like:

```
>>> result = [
...     random.randint(a,b)
...     for args in (((0,50) for _ in range(5)), ((0, 12) for _ in range(2)))
...     for a, b in args
... ]
>>> result
[33, 38, 19, 9, 47, 0, 8]
```

Perhaps, if you want to use itertools, you can do something like:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat, starmap
>>> list(starmap(random.randint, chain(repeat((0,50),5), repeat((0,12),2))))
[16, 47, 40, 21, 15, 12, 4]
```

Both of these approaches are hardly readable and simple. Instead, I would personally go with two for-loops, the naive approach. It would be efficient, simple, and readable. Other than showboating, I see no advantage to the above approaches in production code.